# Crop multiple images in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg

I have multiple images in different resolutions in a folder. With ffmpeg I create a video from all of these.

**My code**

```
await _flutterFFmpeg.execute('-framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "$tempPath/*.jpg" $tempPath/$videoFileName.mov')
```

What I get is a video from all of my images. This works well. But: Many of my images are skewed. So I think I need to crop them. Or is there a function like CSS `background-size: cover`?

Or can I crop images with Dart before creating the video with `ffmpeg`?

Thanks for your helo!

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/image_crop

Comment: Are they skewed in all players? What about ffplay, VLC, or mpv?